# Retornando o nó Pai do firebase

Tags: android, firebase, realtime-database

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá pessoal estou com uma duvida de como pegar o nó pai que seria no caso da imagem o -Kt... fiz alguns codigos porem não da certo.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_criar_cardapio);
    codigo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    ref.child("Mesas").getParent();}
```

Quero atribuir esta String a uma variavel para passar como parâmetro para outra função.

Answer (score 1):

A recuperação de dados no Firebase é feita de modo assíncrono, isso significa que não e possível a atribuição de variáveis fora do escopo onde esta sendo chamada a recuperação dos dados.

```
codigo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

reference = LibraryClass.getFirebase().child("Mesas");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren();

        Log.i("TAG", "key" + snapshot.getKey()); // -Kt8cQVVuvZQ1BYFp7hX

        codigo.setText(snapshot.getKey()); // -Kt8cQVVuvZQ1BYFp7hX
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: tenho uma classe chamada mesa e queria utilizar nela esta função

Comment: Você pode usar, mas tem que ser dentro do escopo da chamada no Firebase.